# Select Box Value not updating in DOM

Tags: angular, typescript

Select box DOM value not updating after value changed in component.ts.

Please check the below code.

```
    <form class="form-horizontal aformgroups" [formGroup]="PurchaseForm"  autocomplete="off">    
    <select class="selectpicker form-control" name="FolioNumberDDl" formComtrolName="FolioNumberDDl">
<option *ngFor="let i of FolioNumberData" [ngValue]="i">{{i}}</option>
</select>
<input type="radio" (change)="changeSelectValue()" />Change Value
</form>


export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  PurchaseForm;

  FolioNumberData: any = [];

  ngOnInit() {
        this.FolioNumberData = ["Select", "1234", "3256", "5643", "5555"]

    this.PurchaseForm = new FormGroup({
      FolioNumberDDl: new FormControl({ value: '1234'})
    });
    this.PurchaseForm.controls.FolioNumberDDl.setValue("1234")
  }
  changeSelectValue(){
    this.PurchaseForm.controls["FolioNumberDDl"].setValue("1234");
    console.log(this.PurchaseForm.controls.FolioNumberDDl.value, "this.PurchaseForm.controls.FolioNumberDDl.value");
  }
```

Stackblitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d3gpku

I've wasted a lot of time on this. Can anyone please help me out of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo:

```
formComtrolName="FolioNumberDDl"
      ^
fomrControlName
```

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6x8yrq?file=src/app/app.component.html)**

Comment: Damn! Thanks, mate :)